# Add-AppxPackage hides actions from output

Tags: powershell

I recently started working with `Add-AppxPackage` and it seems to like truncating certain actions. When running:

```
Add-AppxPackage -Register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\*\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
```

Produces the output:

```
Deployment operation progress: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.People_10.1805.1361.0_neutral_split.language-el_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml 100% Completed
Deployment operation progress: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.People_10.1805.1361.0_neutral_split.language-tr_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml 100% Completed
Deployment operation progress: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.People_10.1805.1361.0_neutral_split.language-zh-hans_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml 100% Completed
Deployment operation progress: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.People_10.1805.1361.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml Initialized
31 activities not shown...
```

I wonder if there is any way to force them to be shown?